# Can't get systemd-networkd to start successfully

Tags: centos7, systemd, systemctl

I have a mini-pc with six network interfaces running CentOS 7.2 with Kernel 3.10 with a minimal install.

I want to name my interfaces net0-net5.  To do so I'm trying to follow the suggestions mentioned here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

In the above article it states that in order to rename my interfaces I need to create .link files and place them in /etc/systemd/network.  This is the new way in which one is required to rename their network interfaces in compliance with the systemd-networkd.

I'm finding however, that the systemd-networkd service won't start and without this service running, I don't think I can name my interfaces at all.

See the following:

```
systemctl --failed -l
  UNIT                     LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
<E2><97><8F> systemd-networkd.service loaded failed failed Network Service
<E2><97><8F> systemd-networkd.socket  loaded failed failed networkd rtnetlink so

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

2 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.


systemctl  status systemd-networkd -l
��● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2011-05-10 01:45:45 UTC; 32min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
  Process: 317 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
 Main PID: 317 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: Unit systemd-networkd.service entered failed state.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service failed.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for systemd-networkd.service
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Service.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: Unit systemd-networkd.service entered failed state.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service failed.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for systemd-networkd.service
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Service.
May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service failed.

systemctl  status systemd-networkd.socket -l                                                             
��● systemd-networkd.socket - networkd rtnetlink socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.socket; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-failed-permanent) since Tue 2011-05-10 01:45:45 UTC; 39min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
           man:rtnetlink(7)
   Listen: route 273 (Netlink)

May 10 01:45:45 localhost systemd[1]: Unit systemd-networkd.socket entered failed state.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

I should mention that NetworkManager is not installed nor is DHClient.  Due to the fact that this was a minimal install I thought I'd show what processes are running:

```
ps -ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:09 /init
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
    7 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
    8 ?        S  /0]
   10 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/1]
   11 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/2]
   12 ?        S      0:00 [rcuob/3]
   13 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_sched]
   14 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/0]
   15 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/1]
   16 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/2]
   17 ?        S      0:00 [rcuos/3]
   18 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/0]
   19 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/1]
   20 ?        S      0:00 [migration/1]
   21 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
   23 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
   24 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
   25 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   26 ?        S<     0:00 [netns]
   27 ?        S<     0:00 [perf]
   28 ?        S<     0:00 [writeback]
   29 ?        S<     0:00 [kintegrityd]
   30 ?        S<     0:00 [bioset]
   31 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
   32 ?        S<     0:00 [md]
   33 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
   34 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:1]
   38 ?        S      0:00 [khungtaskd]
   39 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
   40 ?        SN     0:00 [ksmd]
   41 ?        SN     0:00 [khugepaged]
   42 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
   43 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
   51 ?        S<     0:00 [kthrotld]
   54 ?        S<     0:00 [kmpath_rdacd]
   55 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/1:2]
   56 ?        S<     0:00 [kpsmoused]
   57 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:2]
   58 ?        S<     0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
   77 ?        S<     0:00 [deferwq]
   89 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
   96 ?        S<     0:00 [rpciod]
  109 ?        S      0:00 [kauditd]
  110 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/lvmetad -f
  131 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
  160 ?        S<     0:00 [events_power_ef]
  164 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
  166 ?        S      0:17 [kworker/u8:3]
  167 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
  169 ?        S<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
  172 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
  173 ?        S<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
  174 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u8:4]
  175 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
  176 ?        S<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
  177 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
  178 ?        S<     0:00 [scsi_tmf_3]
  181 ?        S<     0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
  208 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
  209 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
  213 ?        S      0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
  214 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
  215 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-unrsv-conv]
  235 ?        S<sl   0:00 /sbin/auditd -n
  260 ?        SNs    0:00 /usr/sbin/alsactl -s -n 19 -c -E ALSA_CONFIG_PATH=/et
  262 ?        SNsl   0:00 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
  263 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork
  268 ?        Ss     0:00 avahi-daemon: running [linux.local]
  269 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --no
  270 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
  279 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/gpm -m /dev/input/mice -t exps2
  280 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
  281 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
  282 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/gssproxy -D
  284 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  500 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
  503 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
  510 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
  512 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.
  519 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n
  546 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
  547 ?        Ss     0:00 login -- mini
  976 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1022 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/de
 1023 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/de
 1025 ttyS0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 1057 ttyS0    S      0:00 su -
 1058 ttyS0    S      0:00 -bash
 1093 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/anacron -s
15547 ttyS0    R+     0:00 ps -ax
```

One thing I find interesting is that /init is listed as PID 1 but ps -p 1 -o comm= shows that I'm running systemd. Also:

[root@localhost tmp]# pstree

```
systemd-+-agetty
        |-alsactl
        |-anacron
        |-auditd---{auditd}
        |-avahi-daemon---avahi-daemon
        |-crond
        |-dbus-daemon
        |-dnsmasq---dnsmasq
        |-firewalld---{firewalld}
        |-gpm
        |-gssproxy---5*[{gssproxy}]
        |-irqbalance
        |-libvirtd---15*[{libvirtd}]
        |-login---bash---su---bash---pstree
        |-lvmetad
        |-polkitd---5*[{polkitd}]
        |-rsyslogd---2*[{rsyslogd}]
        |-rtkit-daemon---2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
        |-sshd
        |-systemd-journal
        |-systemd-logind
        |-systemd-udevd
        |-tuned---4*[{tuned}]
        `-xinetd
```

Any ideas as to what I should do to get systemd-networkd.service and systemd-networkd.socket to load successfully would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The naming scheme you've proposed is exactly the scheme we've been stuck with for decades and are finally getting rid of! Please save your sanity and reconsider this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exits with `226/NAMESPACE`, which usually means that it was unable to enter a namespace to enable the protection specified in the `.service` file.

There are at least two ways to solve it.

### The easy and less secure way.

Copy `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/`, open the copy with your favorite editor and remove the lines that start with `Protect`. This disables the sandboxing, and should let it start.

### More advanced but more secure

Recompile the kernel with `CONFIG_NAMESPACES=y`.